# I am having difficulty solving this linear algebra equation with all axioms shown (from Elementary linear algebra 8th, 4.2 question 42)

Tags: linear-algebra

Rather than use the standard definitions of addition and scalar multiplication in R3, let these two operations be defined as shown below:

b). $$(x1, y1, z1) +(x2, y2, z2) = (0,0,0)$$
$$c(x, y, z) = (cx, cy, cz)$$

Is R3 a vector space? Justify your answer.

With this type of question, I am struggling to understand the set values on the right (0,0,0). While I feel sort of okay with proving the basic concept, I don't understand this. I keep getting mentally tripped up over trying to close through addition and multiplication but intuitively knowing that the vectors could be another value that doesn't equal (0,0,0) and therefore does not give closure. I would appreciate if someone could walk through the 10 axioms and explain why? Since it is an even answer in the text, there is no given solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is much easier than it seems. The problem is not closure - this addition law is closed, because $(0,0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

But there is no “$0$” vector. Take the vector $(1,0,0)$, for example. No matter what you sum to it, the addition law tells you the result is $(0,0,0)$. $(1,0,0) + (x_1, x_2, x_3) = (0,0,0)$, no matter your choice of $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

I know it can be tricky to wrap your head around new addition definitions, but try to forget the way you usually sum vectors. Pretend you have never learned it before, and someone comes to you and says $1 + a = 0$, for all $a$. What properties does that have, and what properties does it not have? That is the point of this exercise.

To see if it is clear, what is the value of $(1,0,0) + (0,0,0)$, in the context of this exercise?

The question above will help clear your mind of your previous vector addition intuition and help you view the new law of addition only.

Does that help?

Comment: Sorry but im still a little confused. So is this saying that if the left hand side had a (1,0,0) as a vector then the formula would not be able to meet closure? Wouldn't you be able to make the left side also have the inverse which in some cases do allow for closure (-1,0,0)?

Comment: I’ll update my answer to see if it helps, @Michael

Comment: Ok, so we find that addition is closed because (0,0,0) is already included in R3. Why do we multiply the (0,0,0) by (1,0,0) together? Would that be because of the second multiplication rule given? As well, so saying 1+a =0 we just always assume that a would result in -1? so -1, or (1-2) etc?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sort of. If you view “$-1$” as “that thing that sums to $1$ to get $0$”, then yes, everything is $-1$ - “$2$” is $-1$, “$3$” is $-1$, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify: We can say that axiom 1 is closed because 
$$(x1+x2), (y1 +y2), (z1+z2) = (0,0,0)$$
so the first axiom is closed. continuing on through the axioms at 4 (additive identity), it would then fail, because there is no zero vector? as the formula already is a zero vector? Which would then result in addition closure failing, therefore it is not a vector space?
commutative = $$(x2+x1), (y2+y1), (z2 + z1) = (0,0,0)$$ ---> $$(x2, y2, z2) + (x1, y1, z1) = (0,0,0)$$
associative = $$(x1 +x2) ,  ((y1 + y2) , (z1 +z2)) = (0,0,0)$$ --> $$((x1 +x2), (y1 + y2)) , (z1 +z2)$$
etc...

Comment: @Michael, the problem is you are still thinking using the addition law $(x_1, y_1, z_1) + (x_2, y_2, z_2) = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2)$. In the context of this exercise, this is NOT true. I added a question in the end of my answer. See if you can give an answer to that. If you answer that correctly, you will see what I mean by “there is no “$0$” vector”.

Comment: okay, well in the context of this exercise, it would have to equal (0,0,0) would it not? because the left hand side equals (0,0,0) on the right? so would we just consider that the vector (1,0,0) would have a 0 scalar in front of it to make it equal? or am I still getting the concept wrong?
Again, thank you for your help, this has been great so far!

Comment: So far so good - it IS equal to $(0,0,0)$ in the context of this exercise. So the vector $(0,0,0)$ lost the property it usually had, the property that $(0,0,0) + (a,b,c) = (a,b,c)$. As you saw, this is NO LONGER valid. However, there is still the possibility that some other vector now has that property. See if you can get an intuition as to why that cannot be the case, given the addition law.

Comment: okay, so would it be because to have two unique vectors, they cannot be scalar multiples of each other? So having (0,0,0) +(0,0,0) = (0,0,0) wouldn't satisfy $$ (x_2, y_2, z_2)$$ properly?

Comment: Not really... another tip: forget completely about scalar multiplication for the purposes of this exercise, since it was completely unchanged, and so will trivially satisfy everything.

Comment: ok thanks! I think I am figuring it out a bit better now.

Comment: No problem! It may take some time to sink in, but you can read this again, or read the book again, and, if you still don’t quite get it, I’d be happy to elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

A vector space must be a group for the addition. Here it is not a group since it has no identity element.

Comment: Im sorry but I don't quite understand. So it is not a vector space because of the (0,0,0) element? If it were listed as say (x1+x2, y1+y2, z1+z2) how would that go about changing things?

Comment: In a vector space (or in a group if you are familiar with the notion of group), there is a guy called "identity element" : this guy, let's call him $e$, has the property that for every element $a$, you must have $a+e=a$. Here, with your strange law, such a guy cannot exist : indeed, taking $a \neq 0$, you must have $a+e = a$ because $e$ is the identity guy, but also $a+e=0$ because all the sums are zero, so you must have $a=0$. That means that the strange law of your set doesn't allow anybody to be the identity guy : hence it cannot be a vector space.

Comment: hmm ok, I think I understand better now. So since a is the representation of the identity on its own, we don't really have a true identity e.